# Jquery ajax comment posts twice

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am developing a simple ajax post and comment system. The problem is when i make several posts on the page and try to comment on them, every comment goes twice. Have a look on this [pic](http://postimg.org/image/stcewcnix/).

This is my form:

```
<h4>Simple ajax post and comment</h4>
    <form action="" class="post-form">
        <textarea placeholder="type something" name="post_body" id="" class="post"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Post" class="submit">
    </form>
    <div class="result"></div>
```

This is the ajax section:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

        //Submitting main post form
       $(".post-form").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var dataHolder = '';

            //Sending main post
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: 'server.php',
              data: $(this).serialize(),
              success: function(data){
                dataHolder += data;
                runOnComplete();
              },
            });

            //callback function on ajax success
            function runOnComplete() {
                $('.post').val('');
                data = dataHolder;
                var html = '<div class="main-message">' + 'Post: ' + data + '</div><div class="reply"><form action="" class="form-reply"><textarea placeholder="Comment" class="reply-bx" name="reply"></textarea><input type="submit" class="reply-btn" value="comment"></div>';
                $(".result").prepend(html);

                //posting reply
                $('.form-reply').submit(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var ctx = $(this);
                    $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: 'server2.php',
                      data: $(this).serialize(),
                      success: function(data){
                        $('.reply-bx').val('');
                        var h = '<p>' + data + '</p>';
                        ctx.append(h);
                      },
                    });
                });

            }

        });
    });
```

Php files are simple.

server.php:

```
$post = $_POST['post_body'];
echo $post;
```

server2.php:

```
$comment = $_POST['reply'];
echo $comment;
```

You can directly test it from here: 
[Ajax post and comment system](http://www.mykadamtala.com/projects/ajaxcom/) . Make several posts and comment on them. See the comments are going twice.

If you need to see the entire page, have a look here. [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q84btjx5/) . But ajax request will not work here as i noticed.

How to fix it? Each comment should go only one time.

Comment: you never clear out .result, so you'll just keep adding forms with submit handlers.

Comment: fyi - Chrome and IE 11 are handling your form submit as a GET, not a POST request.

Comment: @MarcB Can you specify more how to fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/gb2tpr4h/3/ Try to place this out of the runOnComplete function, beside the other form click function

```
 //posting reply
            $('.form-reply').submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var ctx = $(this);
                $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: 'server2.php',
                  data: $(this).serialize(),
                  success: function(data){
                    $('.reply-bx').val('');
                    var h = '<p>' + data + '</p>';
                    ctx.append(h);
                  },
                });
            });
```

RunOnComplete must be just this:

```
function runOnComplete() {
                $('.post').val('');
                data = dataHolder;
                var html = '<div class="main-message">' + 'Post: ' + data + '</div><div class="reply"><form action="" class="form-reply"><textarea placeholder="Comment" class="reply-bx" name="reply"></textarea><input type="submit" class="reply-btn" value="comment"></div>';
                $(".result").prepend(html);
}
```

EDIT after the various comments: **https://jsfiddle.net/gb2tpr4h/3/** works. The problem is that with two posts you have two .reply where to place the comments and also tow forms...

Comment: i tried your suggestion. But it does not post any comment at all. Can you check again?

Comment: first, just as a check, put an alert in the form-reply submit function in order to be sure the function is called.
then, use $(ctx).serialize() in the the ajax call, not $(this). Let me know how it goes. I'm sure the function is called since I get the alert.

Comment: When I take out form-reply submit event from runOnComplete function. No event gets triggered. I tried to alert(ctx). It does nothing. So no comment is posting.

Comment: the comment part is working for me: https://jsfiddle.net/gb2tpr4h/  the post button is not working, it says it is not  a post request...

Comment: I am going to check out. Thank you

Comment: sorry, made a mistake, look here : https://jsfiddle.net/gb2tpr4h/  

i do not get a good response from the server.... i get object object, but just once

Comment: I tried your way exactly. See here: http://www.mykadamtala.com/projects/ajaxcom/try.php

Comment: It does not seem to be working. Can you inspect it further. Thanks

Comment: OK, i see the problem. You use class reply to identify where to add you comment, so you have multiple place where to add the comment as soon as you create more post. this is working, really!!! sorry for the long time to solve it: jsfiddle.net/gb2tpr4h/3

Comment: I appreciate your help. But its not working for me. Can you download an entire copy here: http://www.mediafire.com/download/7n2g7a98tpnox5z/ajaxcomment.zip           and test it on your local and let me know if it works for you. Thanks

Comment: You can change any html structure if you like to get it done. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87810/discussion-between-jkike-and-saifullah-alam).

Comment: Duplicate comments are gone. Now seeing object. Lets continue on chat. Thank you very much

Comment: Hi with little experiment, I solved the object showing issue. Thank for working on it for long and solve it finally. Thank you